# Error : Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement webdriver (from versions: )

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

hi i new developer at python 
i want to use selenium web driver api and use mac pc and i installation web driver  library

i installation code 'pip install web driver' at pycharm project interpreter  but error

Error definition look this:

```html
  Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5'.




  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement webdriver (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for web driver
```

Note: i use python 3.5 but terminal use 2.7 :(

No matching distribution found for web driver

Could your help me please

Best wishes...

Comment: I am really confused. What are you trying to do exactly? To install selenium you need to install, well, selenium. Not webdriver.  So it should be `pip install selenium`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not very clearly documented, but you cannot install webdriver from pypi but need to install selenium, which then gives you webdriver.

```
sudo pip install selenium
```

should do the trick. Or for modern python:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install selenium
```

You also need to install geckodriver (for Firefox) or chromedriver (for Chrome and Chromium) and have it in your path, to be able to instanciate a webdriver object.

After that things like the below should work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34256762/error-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-webdriver-from")
```

Comment: i am try but thrown error
Traceback (most recent call last):
 
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 77, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),

Comment: I can reproduce this error message on a system without Firefox installed. After the installation of Firefox the error is gone and I get the expected Firefox window.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem on Ubuntu. I wanted to install a specific Selenium version, but I was not sure about the exact tag, as tag on Dockerhub differs a bit.
So my steps were:

1 Go to https://pypi.org/project/selenium/#files

2 Click `Release history` tab
[image]

3 Find a specific version I needed. In my case it was 4.0.0.a7

4 From Linux Terminal execute:

```
pip install selenium==4.0.0.a7
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try the following way, if you do not know the path, use  !apt install chromium-chromedriver

```
!pip install selenium
!pip install webdriver-manager
!apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
!apt install chromium-chromedriver

from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import requests

from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver =webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
sudo python3 -m pip install selenium
```

And after installing selenium, you can install the web driver manager

```
sudo python3 -m pip install webdriver_manager
```