# Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement firefox. No distributions at all found for firefox. Trouble updating firefox

Tags: python, firefox, pip, installation, upgrade

I have Firefox version 32.0.3, and since I have to use selenium package and geckodriver for some automation, I have to update my Firefox, but I am unable to do it. Please somebody let me know.

```
$ python -m pip install --upgrade firefox
#ERROR:
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement firefox (from  
versions: )
No matching distribution found for firefox

$ python -m pip install firefoxCollecting firefox
#ERROR:
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement firefox (from  
versions: )
No matching distribution found for firefox

$ sudo   pip install --upgrade firefox
#ERROR:    
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement firefox
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for firefox
Storing debug log for failure in /home/arvind/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34256762/1531971 (among others)

Answer (score 0):

There is no [firefox at PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/firefox/). `pip` is a **Python** package manager, it can only install Python packages. Firefox is not a Python package and cannot be installed using `pip`.